# ag-Grid: could not find matching row model for rowModelType clientSide

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to recreate this example in the ag-grid docs: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/

and I'm getting this error which I'm not sure why. Everything else has seemed to work fine:

```
ag-Grid: could not find matching row model for rowModelType clientSide
ag-Grid: Row Model "Client Side" not found. Please ensure the ClientSideRowModelModule is loaded using: import '@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model';
```

And here is the exact code in my component:

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { AllModules } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules";
import "@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <ag-grid-angular
      #agGrid
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
      id="myGrid"
      class="ag-theme-balham"
      [modules]="modules"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [masterDetail]="true"
      [detailCellRendererParams]="detailCellRendererParams"
      [rowData]="rowData"
      (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
  `
})
export class TopsheetComponent {
  private gridApi;
  private gridColumnApi;
  public modules  = AllModules;

  private columnDefs;
  private detailCellRendererParams;
  private rowData;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        field: "name",
        cellRenderer: "agGroupCellRenderer"
      },
      { field: "account" },
      { field: "calls" },
      {
        field: "minutes",
        valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 'm'"
      }
    ];
    this.detailCellRendererParams = {
      detailGridOptions: {
        columnDefs: [
          { field: "callId" },
          { field: "direction" },
          { field: "number" },
          {
            field: "duration",
            valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 's'"
          },
          { field: "switchCode" }
        ],
        onFirstDataRendered: function(params) {
          params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
        }
      },
      getDetailRowData: function(params) {
        params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
      },
      template: function(params) {
        var personName = params.data.name;
        return (
          '<div style="height: 100%; background-color: #EDF6FF; padding: 20px; box-sizing: border-box;">' +
          '  <div style="height: 10%;">Name: ' +
          personName +
          "</div>" +
          '  <div ref="eDetailGrid" style="height: 90%;"></div>' +
          "</div>"
        );
      }
    };
  }

  onFirstDataRendered(params) {
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    setTimeout(function() {
      params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(1).setExpanded(true);
    }, 0);
  }

  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    this.http
      .get(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-docs/latest/src/javascript-grid-master-detail/template-callback-customisation/data/data.json"
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.rowData = data;
      });
  }
}
```

It's pretty much identical to the example in the docs.

Here are the dependencies in my `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "^22.1.2",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^22.1.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^22.1.1",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^22.1.1",
}
```

Without all of these dependencies, I run into issues. Is there something I'm missing here? I've added everything correctly in my app.module.ts as well:

```
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
       AgGridModule.withComponents([])
    ]
})
```

^ This was shortened to make it easier to read. But am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: The module where `AgGridModule.withComponents([])`, is `TopSheetComponent` included in its `declarations` array?
Also, try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58821634/trouble-setting-up-sample-table-could-not-find-matching-row-model-for-rowmodel

Comment: @AliF50 yes it is all there :? I saw that answer and was tinkering with what they said but couldn't get it to work either. I mean I'm importing AllModules, so I shouldn't need to import anything else right? I should get them all?

Comment: Yes, I am on a project using Ag-Grid but I am on `21.0.1`. On that version, you don't have to do that stuff.

Comment: which ag-grid? apparently `@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules` doesn't have a version for 21.0.1 :/

Comment: I don't use enterprise in the project I am working on. I will try creating it in stackblitz or locally tonight and will get back to you.

Comment: ahh I gotcha. Yeah I'll continue messing around and see if I can figure something out

Comment: Interesting, I did a `console.log(AllModules)` and the array I got back did have the `ClientSideRowModelModule` in it, which is really weird. I have no idea why it wouldn't be getting picked up though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I apologize for this but I created a StackBlitz and the stupid thing would not allow me to fork. This is not a complete answer but I am providing it here because it is too long for a comment.

Like you, I was going crazy as well and nothing was working. I was getting the same error as you and when I changed it to `ClientSideRowModelModule`, I would get a warning that I cannot use `MasterDetail` because it is not imported.

Try providing the modules globally as outlined here (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-modules/) in `main.ts`. If I can recall correctly, I imported `ModuleRegistry` from `@ag-grid-community/all-modules` (`@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules` did not have it like they show in the documentation), import `AllModules` from `@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules` and then do `ModuleRegistry.registerModules(AllModules);` right before `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule`. This removed the errors and warnings (just the error/warning of not providing a license key). The theming of it was off in my view but maybe that can be an easy fix.

IMO, this is bad documentation/implementation from `ag-grid`, seems to be all over the place. For instance, if you can't copy and paste their demonstration solution and for it not to work, pretty bad if you ask me.

Comment: OMG You are a life saver. This managed to work, especially the part where `ModuleRegistry.registerModules(AllModules);` right before `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule` - Thankyou so much. I think they recently updated to version `22.0.0` so I can understand if every single thing isn't perfect. But also my styles seem to work just fine for me :) Maybe because I'm on the newer version?

Comment: I was using latest version as well, maybe because I was using stackblitz and I configured it wrong.