# Register AG GRID Master detail module in angular 17

Tags: ag-grid, master-detail, angular17

I am getting below warning when I go to the component

```
AG Grid: unable to use masterDetail as the MasterDetailModule is not registered. Check if you have registered the module:
           
    import { ModuleRegistry } from '@ag-grid-community/core';
    import { MasterDetailModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/master-detail';
    
    ModuleRegistry.registerModules([ MasterDetailModule ]);
```

I tried registering it in the same module itself. My project does not have app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

The following post will help:

[Trouble setting up sample table. "Could not find matching row model for rowModelType clientSide"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58821634/trouble-setting-up-sample-table-could-not-find-matching-row-model-for-rowmodel)

Also refer to ag grid document below:

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/modules/